# Ruby on Rails: Why does calling a partial in my views take an extended time to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I'm calling three partials in my recipes/_cuisines.html.erb file:

```
  <%= render "recipes/cuisines/denmark.html %>
  <%= render "recipes/cuisines/spain.html %>
  <%= render "recipes/cuisines/italy.html %>
```

Nothing else is in that file. The partials are just static content with no collections. This is what I get from my logs:

```
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_denmark.html.erb (4.6ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_spain.html.erb (2.3ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_italy.html.erb (5.3ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/_cuisines.html.erb (161.5ms) [cache miss]
```

If I remove one of the partials, I get something like:

```
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_denmark.html.erb (4.6ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_spain.html.erb (2.3ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/_cuisines.html.erb (101.7ms) [cache miss]
```

Removing another partial, I get:

```
  Rendered recipes/cuisines/_denmark.html.erb (4.6ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered recipes/_cuisines.html.erb (50.5ms) [cache miss]
```

Removing every partial, I get something like this:

```
  Rendered recipes/_cuisines.html.erb (0.9ms) [cache miss]
```

It seems that it takes an extraordinary time to render each partial even if the partial itself is very small. Do you know what causes that and what I can do to call partials faster? Is it recommended to not call partials at all?

(I'm using Rails 5.1.1 and ruby 2.5.0dev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have pasted logs from development environment.
If so, then it is due to `config.cache_classes` which is default to `false` for development and to `true` for test and production environments as mentioned in the rails guides.

> config.cache_classes controls whether or not application classes and
>   modules should be reloaded on each request. Defaults to false in
>   development mode, and true in test and production modes.
>
> config.action_view.cache_template_loading controls whether or not
>   templates should be reloaded on each request. Defaults to whatever is
>   set for config.cache_classes.

I suggest to run the application in `test` or `production` environments and then check the logs.

Comment: I didn't know it could be so simple :) Thanks so much Pramod!